# Custom fields in the Report Templates

Tags: custom-fields, reports

I've managed to generate new fields but I can't add them into the report templates. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Make sure they are marked as searchable. On your:
civicrm/admin/custom/group/field?reset=1&action=browse&gid=1

(assuming it's your first Custom Data set)

Check the Searchable? Column; If you toggle that to Yes - then reports that pull in custom fields will show yours at the bottom of Columns and Filters - e.g.:

[image]
The Searchable? = Yes field shows is select-able in the Report:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Remember to mark the answer as accepted 